# How can I know if a given string is hex, rgb, rgba or hsl color using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, hex, rgb

I used regex for the hex. `/^\#([a-fA-F0-9]{6}|[a-fA-F0-9]{3})$/` but I dont know what I should for do for finding rgb, rgba and hsl. I am getting the input in string. For example, the input will contain "rgb(0,0,0)"or "rgb(0,0,0,0.2)".

Comment: THx for the great community. This website has been a heaven.

Comment: do you want to know _if_ it's a color, or what type of color format it is?

Comment: @dandavis I would like to validate if what the user input is true or not. So I would need to know the type of color format + if it is llegal for that format. I am not converting anything

Comment: Hi. Take a look at the following site: http://upshots.org/javascript/javascript-color-class
It's a color class. use it or take a look at the code, to see how they parse / validate color values.

Comment: @JoshuaK it seems it has **var isHex = /^#?([0-9a-f]{3}|[0-9a-f]{6})$/i;
 var isHSL = /^hsla?\((\d{1,3}?),\s*(\d{1,3}%),\s*(\d{1,3}%)(,\s*[01]?\.?\d*)?\)$/;
 var isRGB = /^rgba?\((\d{1,3}%?),\s*(\d{1,3}%?),\s*(\d{1,3}%?)(,\s*[01]?\.?\d*)?\)$/;**   But what should the input LOOK LIKE?

Comment: a string... like you need it. take a look at the `parse(value)` method of the class

Comment: @JoshuaK did u write that? Wow impressive sir

Comment: No. Just found it ;) But the code is not that hard. If you have any questions feel free to ask. I will help you with any problems as best I can.

Comment: @JoshuaK isRGB.test("rgba(10,25,1,11)")  doesn't work. It returns true.

Comment: Aww man the isHSL doesnt work either. It fails..

Comment: sure it returns true. rgb and rgba is the same. rgb(0,0,0) = rgba(0,0,0,1). you can show all rgb as rgba by setting alpha=1. hsl is the same.

Comment: @JoshuaK  isRGB.test("rgba(10,25,1,11)") !== true because **THE ALPHA must be between 0.0 to 1.0 for the RGBA. RBA doesn't have an alpha**

Comment: ahhh get ya. I thought you just wanne find them, but you also want to validate them. so you have to change the expression a little bit. Gimme some time. sure: RGB has an alpha value. it is implicit 1.

Comment: here you go. I changed the regular expression in a way you need it: http://jsfiddle.net/gq008ana/ -- I splitted the regex in rgb and rgba and modified it in a way, that number checking is activ.

Comment: @JoshuaK The regex fails to match "`249`". Use this to match 0 to 255: `([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])`

Comment: @Mariano u sure 249 failed to match? any img? proof?

Comment: Test it yourself. It returns false. This page will give you a regex for a range: http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range

Comment: @Mariano says something fails in ur regex check the comment above

Answer (score 20):

There are different options here:

#### 1. Use a dummy element

Use the browser's validation. Create a *dummy* HTML element, assign the color and check if it's set. This is by far the best option. It's not only easier, but it will also allow forward compatibility.

```JavaScript
function CheckValidColor(color) {
    var e = document.getElementById('divValidColor');
    if (!e) {
        e = document.createElement('div');
        e.id = 'divValidColor';
    }
    e.style.borderColor = '';
    e.style.borderColor = color;
    var tmpcolor = e.style.borderColor;
    if (tmpcolor.length == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

// function call
var inputOK = CheckValidColor('rgb( 0, 0, 255)');
```

This will return `true` for all colors accepted by the browser, even in cases you may consider invalid.

---

#### 2. Capture the numbers with regex and validate in code

If you capture anything that *looks like a number*, you will be able to validate each parameter individually with `IF clauses`. This will allow you to provide better feedback to the user.

**a) #hex:**

```regex
^(#)((?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{3}){1,2})$
```

The hash is also captured for consistency with the following expression. [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yF0uY1/1)

**b) rgb(), rgba(), hsl() and hsla():**

```regex
^(rgb|hsl)(a?)[(]\s*([\d.]+\s*%?)\s*,\s*([\d.]+\s*%?)\s*,\s*([\d.]+\s*%?)\s*(?:,\s*([\d.]+)\s*)?[)]$
```

This will create captures for the function and each parameter. [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yF0uY1/2)

---

#### 3. Validate with one monster regex:

This option is not recommended, mainly because it's quite difficult to read, it won't guarantee to match all use cases, and it will give you a headache if you try to debug it. The following regex validates the number of parameters allowed and ranges.

**a) #hex:** `^#(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{3}){1,2}$` [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yF0uY1/3)

**b) rgb():** `^rgb[(](?:\s*0*(?:\d\d?(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*%)?|\.\d+\s*%|100(?:\.0*)?\s*%|(?:1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:\.\d+)?)\s*(?:,(?![)])|(?=[)]))){3}[)]$` [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yF0uY1/4)

**c) rgba():** `^^rgba[(](?:\s*0*(?:\d\d?(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*%)?|\.\d+\s*%|100(?:\.0*)?\s*%|(?:1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:\.\d+)?)\s*,){3}\s*0*(?:\.\d+|1(?:\.0*)?)\s*[)]$` [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yF0uY1/5)

**d) hsl():** `^hsl[(]\s*0*(?:[12]?\d{1,2}|3(?:[0-5]\d|60))\s*(?:\s*,\s*0*(?:\d\d?(?:\.\d+)?\s*%|\.\d+\s*%|100(?:\.0*)?\s*%)){2}\s*[)]$` [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yF0uY1/6)

**e) hsla():** `^hsla[(]\s*0*(?:[12]?\d{1,2}|3(?:[0-5]\d|60))\s*(?:\s*,\s*0*(?:\d\d?(?:\.\d+)?\s*%|\.\d+\s*%|100(?:\.0*)?\s*%)){2}\s*,\s*0*(?:\.\d+|1(?:\.0*)?)\s*[)]$` [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yF0uY1/7)

**All toghether now:**

With the above expressions, we can create this one-liner to validate all legal color values:

```regex
^(?:#(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{3}){1,2}|(?:rgb[(](?:\s*0*(?:\d\d?(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*%)?|\.\d+\s*%|100(?:\.0*)?\s*%|(?:1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:\.\d+)?)\s*(?:,(?![)])|(?=[)]))){3}|hsl[(]\s*0*(?:[12]?\d{1,2}|3(?:[0-5]\d|60))\s*(?:\s*,\s*0*(?:\d\d?(?:\.\d+)?\s*%|\.\d+\s*%|100(?:\.0*)?\s*%)){2}\s*|(?:rgba[(](?:\s*0*(?:\d\d?(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*%)?|\.\d+\s*%|100(?:\.0*)?\s*%|(?:1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:\.\d+)?)\s*,){3}|hsla[(]\s*0*(?:[12]?\d{1,2}|3(?:[0-5]\d|60))\s*(?:\s*,\s*0*(?:\d\d?(?:\.\d+)?\s*%|\.\d+\s*%|100(?:\.0*)?\s*%)){2}\s*,)\s*0*(?:\.\d+|1(?:\.0*)?)\s*)[)])$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yF0uY1/8)

Or the regex enthusiasts can check this [huge regex](https://regex101.com/r/yF0uY1/9), with 148 color names. But I would never recommend using that pattern. Please use the first option, creating a dummy element, which is the only way to cover all use cases for the browser.

Comment: Your CheckValidColor() might not work. Since u are checking the **tmpcolor.length == 0**, length.

Comment: So? It will be an empty string if you try to set an incorrect color, hence the length of that string will be == 0... Can you provide an example where it would fail?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about other browsers but in chrome the color will only be set if its valid:

```
var isValidColor = function(color) {
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.style.backgroundColor = color;
  return el.style.backgroundColor ? true : false;
};

console.log(isValidColor('#ff0000')); // true
console.log(isValidColor('rgb(0, 0)')); // false
```

It will have it's pitfalls though, because Chrome will do auto rounding of numbers:

```
// 0, 0, 256 is not a valid color, but this says yes
console.log(isValidColor('rgb(0, 0, 256)')); // true
```

Comment: really good answer, about the same as i was going to offer; the only non-brittle solution here. one step further would be to return valid computed properties in the case of an invalid range...

Comment: RegExp won't tell you if something works or not, whereas a system like the one above tells you that it actually works. If needed, you can follow up with validity/range restrictions after the well-formed input testing  performed by the native color parser.