# JavaScript fix for change text shadow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need some help regarding the JavaScript function I'm using which changes the text shadow based on the user input field.
It is working fine when I add the complete value like `3px 3px 3px red`.

But I'm trying to make it like:

> Javascript automatically adds `3px 3px 3px`. And the user has to write the shadow color only.

Here is the JavaScript function:

```
function changeBackground(obj) {
    document.getElementById("coltext").style.textShadow = obj.value;
}
```

And this is the HTML I'm using

```
<input id="color" type="text" onchange="changeBackground(this);" />
<br /><span id="coltext">CHANGE THE SHADOW OF THIS TEXT</span>
```

I think there should be something added in front of `obj.value`. As `obj.value` will be the color which user will add.

Comment: It is just an empty text field. I add 3px 3px 3px green into the field and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try *keyup* event and the *+* (concat operator on strings)

HTML

```
<span id="coltext">This is some text</span>
<br />
<input type="text" id="model" />
```

Javascript

```
var input = document.getElementById('model');
var text = document.getElementById('coltext');

function changeTextShadow(event) {
  var value = input.value;
  var parts = value.split(' ');
  text.style.textShadow = '3px 3px 3px ' + value;
}

input.addEventListener('keyup', changeTextShadow);
```

Working example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VpXmWr

---

In case you want this to run when the user press "enter". you can check the key pressed by accessing event's keyCode

```
function changeTextShadow(event) {
  if ( event.keyCode === 13 ) { //enter's keycode is 13 (ascii code)
    var value = input.value;
    var parts = value.split(' ');
    text.style.textShadow = '3px 3px 3px ' + value; 
  }
}
```

Working example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BWrQXX

Comment: OMG! This is exactly what I need. Thanks a lot. 

The only thing which is missing is, the old code runs when I press enter. Is that possible in this too? Thanks again.

Comment: @Samlano you can check they keypressed. I added  working example to the answer :)

Comment: Hell yeah!! Thanks a lot. Upvoted. Although this was quick.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you could simply prepend the string `3px 3px 3px`, like:

```
target.style.textShadow = '3px 3px 3px ' + value;
```

But it will fail for a lot of user inputs and uses a magic string.

---

To make it more configurable, you could store the config in an object:

```
var config = {
    offsetX: '3px',
    offsetY: '3px',
    blurRadius: '3px',
    color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
};
```

To disallow wrong inputs, [test the input for a valid color](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32673760/1456376):

```
function testColor(color) {
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.style.backgroundColor = color;
    return el.style.backgroundColor ? true : false;
}
```

Finally update your function to create the correct value. This example has a fallback to the configured color, if a wrong value is given:

```
function updateTextShadow(el) {
    var value = config.offsetX + ' ' + config.offsetY + ' ' + config.blurRadius + ' ';

    value += testColor(el.value) ? el.value : config.color;

    target.style.textShadow = value;
}
```

**Further improvements**

- Instead of re-querying the same DOM element again and again, store it in a variable, like `var target = document.getElementById('coltext');`.
- Instead of using a fallback, you could also present a message to the user: `if (!testColor(el.value)) { alert('not valid'); }`.
- Instead of using the `testColor` function, you could test whether the shadow was applied and show an error message, if not.

**Demo**

[Try before buy](https://jsfiddle.net/3oyqymsz/)